# Ad Hoc test install failing

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.3, box2d-iphone

I have a project I can successfully build/install using developer/debug to a device or simulator.

When I make an ad hoc build i can build-run onto the simulator, but not onto the device.

I'm trying to perform a direct install because the ad hoc installed app is crashing (nil added to array) where the debug version is not.

I also have tried to attach to the running ad hoc installed app.  The app will run indefinitely (but crash if i perform a particular use case.) But if I attempt to attach to the running app, it will crash.

It happens to be a Box2d/Cocos2d application - but i don't have any reason to think they are the cause.  Xcode 4.3.2, iPhone4 iOS 5.1

the message when build-and-run is attempted:
`error: failed to launch '/Users/bshirley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foo-bar-evrbckppmbsspqhezhleaxkmymxn/Build/Products/Adhoc-iphoneos/foo-bar.app/foo-bar' -- failed to get the task for process 6892`

Anyone have some insight into the problem or tracking it down?

---

Edit, I thought I'd add some key words so searches might be more likely to find:

One issue with diagnosing the post-mortem crash was that the stack trace was not symbolized in the Device Logs of the Organizer in Xcode.  That left me with 6+ deep stack trace w/i my code and no real reason to determine where it actually was.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a release build, the app will (in a default setup) have a flag preventing outside processes from hooking into it (for security reasons).  This includes the debugger.  If you try, you will get the exact error message you indicate.

*EDIT* Sorry, small error.  A release build alone will not cause this.  A build with an adhoc certificate will cause this, because it is meant for final install on a device (not debugging).

Answer (score 0):

If borrrden is correct (and it seems reasonable that he is, connecting one app to a signed running app would be a security issue), I can't actively debug the adhoc app.

The most useful thing i found for tracking down this issue, is `Build Settings -> Symbols Hidden by Default` - this value is only `NO` for `debug`.  Setting it for `NO` on `adhoc` allowed me to see the entire stack trace when inspecting the `Device Logs` in the Xcode Organizer.

That led me to the particular method that was invoking the crash causing issue.  Which led to the question why *wasn't* it crashing in the debug build.  Didn't have time to diagnose that, just fix the problem.